# Path planning and object manipulation

Tags: ros, navigation, path, move-base, manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a differential drive robot with a gripper, which is attached to it's front. The robot needs to collect objects on a plain map with some obstacles. I understand how to use move_base to create path and execute from the center of the robot to any point on map, but I don't know how to create path, which finishes with the gripper facing the object. How can it be done with move_base or any other ROS package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204256/path-planning-and-object-manipulation./) by [Vsevolod](https://answers.ros.org/users/21774/vsevolod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The interfaces to move_base require that you chose an orientation as well as a position.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0